# Remove <!DOCTYPE from output of property.storeToXML

Tags: java, xml

Following are the sample of my code.

```
OutputStream outs = response.getOutputStream();
property.put("xyz", serverpath);
property.put("*abc", serverIPAddress);

property.storeToXML(outs, null, "UTF-8");           
outs.close();
```

I don't require `DOCTYPE` declaration. How to remove it?

Current output is:

[image]

Comment: If the issue is **online access to the dtd UR**L, you might be interested in using **[XML catalogs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Catalog)** to have a local copy of the dtd(s) to be used instead.
The DOCTYPE then can remain as-is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like most of the Properties class, you can't change it. Instead, capture the XML string produced, modify it, then send it out manually.

```
property.put("xyz", "serverpath");
property.put("*abc", "serverIPAddress");
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
property.storeToXML(out, null, "UTF-8");
String str = out.toString("UTF-8").replaceAll("<!DOCTYPE[^>]*>\n", "");
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
OutputStream outs = response.getOutputStream();
outs.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
outs.close();
```

FYI [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) is an in-memory output stream you can use to capture and retrieve what was written to it. Because a `Properties` object is in practice not going to have many entries, this approach does not pose a memory consumption risk.

Comment: thanx. best answer for my perspective. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you already have string and want to remove it then you can make use of this

```
str.replaceAll("<!DOCTYPE((.|\n|\r)*?)\">", "");
```

Picked from here: http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=270

Answer (score 2):

Doctype is a header component, it shouldn't matter for most purposes.

If you really want to remove it, you should write the result to a StringWriter or ByteArrayOutputStream and remove the unwanted content.